# How to implement equals without exposing fields?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a `Dog` class which has a field `private final int age` and a method `public Dog ageBy(Time time)` which returns new Instance of the dog every time invoked. A `Dog` class is not just immutable but doesn't have any `get` methods to return it's age, in other words dog's contract doesn't allow him to say his age (why? cause there is no talking dogs), he can only 'bark', 'sleep' and do other dog's stuff.

But `Dog` can be compared with other dogs by age. To do so I need to override `public equals(Object o)` method in `Dog` class. But the problem is that there is no way to compare it, because I can't access passed dogs age.

Question: How to implement equals method without exposing any fields of object?

Comment: All `Dog` instances have access to the `private` fields of other `Dog` instances.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any method can access `private` fields of the same class, so you can write the equals accessing directly the fields, without needs of getters.

Here is an example:

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       // Test for null, and type
       ...
       Point p = (Point) obj;
       return x == p.x && y == p.y;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

An object can access `private` instances of other object of the same class, so you don't need getters in `equals`.